# Create new Laravel project using Docker WSL2 cUrl Error Windows

Tags: php, laravel, docker, curl

I'm trying to start a new laravel project with Docker, basically I followed the description on laravel documentation.

I run this command : `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-ap`p | bash

And I got this response that I don't understand :

```
applet de commande Invoke-WebRequest à la position 1 du pipeline de la commande
```

Fournissez des valeurs pour les paramètres suivants :
Uri:  https://laravel.build/example-app
curl : Lecteur introuvable. Il n'existe aucun lecteur nommé « https ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1

- curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (https:String) [Invoke-WebRequest], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
  ```

Please help me

Comment: You try to execute bash script in windows console. first enter in wsl by typing `bash` - than `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work